# Sensored BLDC Motor from Hoverboard - Protect driver?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, induction

I'm designing a controller and Arduino library for a brushless DC motor, which was used in a Hoverboard. Its specs are 36V, 200W. I use the standard circuit that is suggested everywhere on the internet (only showoing the power electronics, not the Hall sensors):

[image]

Here, VCC is 15V, and the +24V pin is currently also set to VCC (They are sourced from the same power supply).

I have added a cascade of LEDs to the 3 half-bridges to see, where the current flows through the coils of the motor. As the driver, I use IRS2183, as the MOSFETS, I use N-channel IRFZ48N, which should easily manage the load.

I experience the following problem: I control the motor with PWM (input in the correct order into Lin and Hin of the drivers) and it spins nicely. Sometimes, it happens that the motor abruptly stops or shortly blocks and then proceeds rotation. I believe this is due to some bug in my control software. **In roughly 50% of these cases, one of the drivers burns (i.e. it becomes hot, and it wont work anymore, I have to exchange it).** They do not become hot during normal operation.

My questions:

- Is it from the above circuit possible, that the drivers burn because of the motor, or is it my particular setup of the schematic (built on a breadboard)
- What can I do to protect the drivers from burning, when the motor apruptly stops or otherwise induces high voltage into the FETs?
- Is it harmful, when I run the motor with 15V, instead of its 36V nominal voltage?

Comment: The driver fails? The IR2183D? Or the FET fails? Or both?

Comment: The driver fails, i.e. the 8pin IC IRS2183. They burn and get destroyed by whatever reason. The FETs are fine.

Comment: Is the damage closer to one pin or the other on the IC? Or can you tell?

Comment: I cant say which pin it is, the IC just doesn't work anymore, i.e. it does not follow the logic that is described in the datasheet.

Comment: The only think I can come up with is that maybe the diode is somehow faulty and letting the driver get exposed to high voltage? Not sure why this would happen.